# my swift project using firebase isn't throwing errors if there's a login error

Tags: swift, xcode

so im making this chat app with the help of firebase on swift 5 and i want to alert to the user whenever the login fails but after debugging it seems like it isnt throwing any errors and hence the alert is not getting triggered

//

here's my code snippet .///

[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cR0GT.png)

and here i've copy pasted

```html
//
//  Created by Syed Affan on 1/8/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Syed Affan. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAnalytics

class File2: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var userNameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var confirmTextField: UITextField!
    
    
    
override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
    let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "BowlbyOneSC-Regular", size: 25)!]
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = attributes
    
    navigationItem.title = "Sign Up"
}
    
    @IBAction func signUpButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
 
        if let user = userNameTextField.text , let password = passwordTextField.text{
            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: user, password: password) {authresults, error in
                if error != nil{
                    print("error")
                    self.alertAction(title: "Error", message: "No User Found")
                    
                }
                else{
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "mainViewSign", sender: self)
                }
                
            }
            }
        
    }
    func alertAction(title : String ,  message : String){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: title, style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { (action) in
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

**strong text**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code says that you're trying to 'create' a new user by using `Auth.auth().createUser()` method, and not perform a login. So, I suppose you need to be clear about your code first.
If you want to throw a login error, first create a login button and add its login action. Then, use the code given below:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { [weak self] authResult, error in
  guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
  // ...
}
```

For more details, please check this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start#sign_in_existing_users).